# Why i can't use Variable in TRecord?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, record

I'm with a doubt about the TRecord use.

Can i use a VAR in a record property?

For example:

My record:

```
TStyleEvalue = record
    ID: Integer;
    Value: TFontStyles;
    Name: String;

  end;
```

When i try to attribute VAR in the `Name` property as the code below:

```
StylesEvalueArray : array[0..15] of TStyleEvalue = (
    (ID: 00; Value: [];                                        Name: LB_NORMAL),
    (ID: 01; Value: [fsBold];                                  Name: LB_NEGRITO),
    (ID: 02; Value: [fsItalic];                                Name: LB_ITALICO),
    (ID: 03; Value: [fsBold,fsItalic];                         Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_ITALICO),
    (ID: 04; Value: [fsUnderline];                             Name: LB_SUBLINHADO),
    (ID: 05; Value: [fsBold,fsUnderline];                      Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_SUBLINHADO),
    (ID: 06; Value: [fsItalic,fsUnderline];                    Name: LB_ITALICO+', '+LB_SUBLINHADO),
    (ID: 07; Value: [fsBold,fsItalic,fsUnderline];             Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_ITALICO+', '+LB_SUBLINHADO),
    (ID: 08; Value: [fsStrikeOut];                             Name: LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 09; Value: [fsBold,fsStrikeOut];                      Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 10; Value: [fsItalic,fsStrikeOut];                    Name: LB_ITALICO+', '+LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 11; Value: [fsBold,fsItalic,fsStrikeOut];             Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_ITALICO+', '+LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 12; Value: [fsUnderline,fsStrikeOut];                 Name: LB_SUBLINHADO+', '+LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 13; Value: [fsBold,fsUnderline,fsStrikeOut];          Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_SUBLINHADO+', '+LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 14; Value: [fsItalic,fsUnderline,fsStrikeOut];        Name: LB_ITALICO+', '+LB_SUBLINHADO+', '+LB_TACHADO),
    (ID: 15; Value: [fsBold,fsItalic,fsUnderline,fsStrikeOut]; Name: LB_NEGRITO+', '+LB_ITALICO+', '+LB_SUBLINHADO+', '+LB_TACHADO)
  );
```

I get this error message:

> [Error] FormFontChange.pas(102): Constant expression expected

This error happens at all the lines of this array.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a [constant expression](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions), you can only use true constants and some other things, see link, but no variables and no typed constants. If `LB_NORMAL` is a variable, you can forget it. Makes sense, since variables do usually not remain constant. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring a typed constant. The values that you use for the typed constant must be what is known as constant expressions. The documentation can be found here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Typed_Constants

For the example here, the relevant section is that covering [record constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants). The documentation says:

> To declare a record constant, specify the value of each field - as fieldName: value, with the field assignments separated by semicolons - in parentheses at the end of the declaration. The values must be represented by constant expressions.

The compiler is telling you that `LB_NORMAL` is not a constant expression. We don't know what `LB_NORMAL` is, but it must be a constant expression compatible with the type `string`. For instance:

```
const
  LB_NORMAL = 'foo';
```

would suffice. Or even:

```
const
  foo = 'foo';
  bar = 'bar';
  LB_NORMAL = foo + bar;
```

However you define `LB_NORMAL`, it is not a constant expression. You may need to consult the documentation for [constant expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions) to understand how to proceed.

You seem to imply in the text, although it is not clear and sadly you did not show what `LB_NORMAL` is, that `LB_NORMAL` is a variable. Well, a variable is not a constant expression. If `LB_NORMAL` is indeed a variable, you will have to declare `StylesEvalueArray` as a variable also.